# Is it possible to transfer the history of commands from one system to another?

Tags: bash, command-history

I am going to have all my data transferred to a new PC. Is it possible to transfer the command history of the previous Linux to the new system as well? So that when I type the `history` command, I get the same results as I did on the old system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using Bash then the history is kept in the file, `.bash_history`, in your home directory.

This file can be copied from one system to another, it's just a text file.

#### Example

```
$ tail -4 ~/.bash_history
#1385239516
alias|grep cdc
#1385240451
exit
```

The file is filled with lines that include a timestamp followed by the command that ran at that timestamp.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the history file can be stored elsewhere, if the `HISTFILE` environment variable is re-set. Its default is certainly ~/.bash_history, however.

Answer (score 2):

If you transfer the home directory contents as well, then yes. In bash it's /home/user/.bash_history, for example.

Answer (score 1):

FYI for ZSH users, the equivalent file is `~/.zsh_history` (tried on macOS 13)

```
 ~/code/workplace  zsh --version
zsh 5.9 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)
 ~/code/workplace
 ~/code/workplace  head -n 5 ~/.zsh_history
: 1684505621:0;git
: 1684505621:0;git
: 1684505621:0;exit
: 1684505621:0;exit
: 1684492177:0;vi ~/.zshrc
```